# How do I know the command to check if an application is installed on my computer or not?

Tags: software-installation, vmware

I had recently installed a version of VMWare Workstation that I had to uninstall and to look for instructions about doing so I came across [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1754180) thread.

It stated writing this command to see if there was any version of VMWare Workstation installed:

> vmware-installer -l

So what I want to know is, just like the quoted command for VMWare, how do I know about other commands that exist to let me know if a particular product is installed on my computer or not?

Thanks for looking in.

Answer (score 3):

Type in a terminal:

```
dpkg --list | grep -i name-of-application
```

Comment: Any chance you could break down the structure of the command to explain the semantics of the syntax?

Comment: Search (grep) "name-of-application" ignoring case (-i) in (|) the output provided by "dpkg --list". Try "dpkg --list" alone to understand.

Answer (score 2):

### Using aptitude

If a package was installed using the package manager, running the following command will display packages that are installed and that contain the word `keyword` in their name:

```
aptitude search '~i keyword'
```

#### Example

```
aptitude search '~i samba'
```

This returns the following list of packages on my system:

```
i   samba                                                                  - SMB/CIFS file, print, and login server for Unix
i   samba-common                                                           - common files used by both the Samba server and client
i   samba-common-bin                                                       - common files used by both the Samba server and client
i   system-config-samba                                                    - GUI for managing samba shares and users
```

The `i` stands for installed.

### Using which

You can also use `which` if you know the name of the executable you are searching for; it will return `executable-name`'s path if it is installed, and nothing otherwise.

```
which executable-name
```

#### Example

```
which system-config-samba
```

This returns the following on my system:

```
/usr/sbin/system-config-samba
```

I therefore know that `system-config-samba` is installed, and I know where.

Comment: Oh good. Thanks. That means it would require me to know the exact identifier of the program I'm looking for right? And what if I did not use aptitude? In this case, I had installed VMWare from a .bundle file.

Comment: Yes, you would need to know the name of the executable file that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

mm you can also try to install again the application ($ sudo apt-get install "the name of the app) and if it is really installed it will appear "(the name of the program) it's already at the lastest version"